# System with bounded delays : uniqueness theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $F:[t_0,\beta) \times C_D \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ continuous and Locally Lipschitzian. then, given any $\phi \in C_D$, eqs. $x'(t)=F(t,x_t)$ and $ x_{t_0}=\phi $ (initial value condition) have at most one solution on $[t_0 -r,\beta_{1})$ for any $\beta_{1}\in (t_0,\beta]$.

$C_D=C([a,b],\mathbb{R}^n)$ with norm of $\phi\in C_D$ is Euclidean Norm. and $x_{t_0}=\phi $ means $x(t_0+\sigma)=\phi(\sigma)$ or letting $t=t_0+\sigma$, then $x(t)=\phi (t-t_0)$ for $t_0-r\leq t\leq t_0$.

proof : 
 suppose (for contradiction) that for some $\beta_{1}\in(t_0,\beta]$ there are two solutions $x$ and $x_{1}$ mapping $[t_0-r,\beta_{1})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x\neq x_1$. Let 
$t_1 =inf{\{t\in(t_0,\beta_{1}):x(t)\neq x_1 (t)\}}$.
then $t_0\leq t_1\leq \beta_{1}$ and 
$x(t)=x_1$ for $t_0-r\leq t \leq t_1$.
Since $(t_1,x_1)\in[t_0,\beta_{1})\times C_D$, there exist numbers $a>0$ and $b>0$ such that the set 
$C$ is $[t_1,t_1+a]\times{\{\psi\in C : ||\psi-x_{t_1}||_r\leq b\} }$ is contained in $[t_0,\beta)\times C_D$ and $F$ Lipschitzian on $C$ with Lipschitz constant is $K$.

I can proof that there is $\delta \in(0,a]$ such that $(t,x_t)\in C$ and $(t,x_{1t})\in C$ for $t_1 \leq t \leq t_1+\delta$. more over both $x$ and $x_1$ satisfy 
$x(t)=\phi(t-t_0)$ for $t_0-r\leq t \leq t_0$ 
and $x(t)=\phi(0)+ \int_{t_0}^t F(s,x_s)ds$ for $t_0\leq t \leq \beta_1$. Thus, for $t_1\leq t\leq t_1+\delta$, 
$||x(t)-x_1(t)||=\int_{t_0}^t [F(s,x_s)-F(s,x_{1s})]ds$ 
               $\leq\int_{t_0}^t K||x_s-x_{1s}||_r ds$

now since the right hand side is an increasing function of $t$ and since $||x(t)-x_1(t)||=0$ for $t_1-r\leq t\leq t_1+\delta$, then

$||x_t-x_{1t}||_r \leq \int_{t_0}^t K||x_s-x_{1s}||_r ds$ for $t_1\leq t<t_1+\delta$. 
I am stuck in here, any one can continue this proof by using generalized gronwall lemma to find the conclusion that $x(t)=x_1(t)$ ?
and please correct that proof.